# shorter css (stylus) selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, stylus

How do I aggregate/ make shorter these stylus selectors?:

```
#map > div.mapboxgl-control-container > div.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left > div:nth-child(1) > button
#map > div.mapboxgl-control-container > div.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left > div:nth-child(2) > button.mapboxgl-ctrl-icon.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in
#map > div.mapboxgl-control-container > div.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left > div:nth-child(2) > button.mapboxgl-ctrl-icon.mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out
#map > div.mapboxgl-control-container > div.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left > div:nth-child(2) > button.mapboxgl-ctrl-icon.mapboxgl-ctrl-compass
#editControl > button
  min-height 0 !important
  border-radius 0 !important
```

Just having `.button` as selector would work but does have unwanted side-effects, so that's a restriction. The css of the first 3 selectors comes from [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/dist/mapbox-gl.css).

Comment: do you have an option to add `id` attributes to your html?

Comment: @haxxxton yes for the editControl, for the others: no.

Comment: are their other `!important` styles that you're having to override on these elements? could you provide the html you're looking please, as there may be a more efficient traversal.

Comment: @haxxxton Added a restriction on just using .button as selector. And a reference to the css used.

Comment: could you please still provide the html you're using. mapbox has a number of plugins and style change options out-of-the-box, and so your particular mileage may vary form a standard solution. We cannot know for sure unless we know what code you're using

Comment: @haxxxton sorry don't know how to answer your html request as using 'view page source' just gives me irrelevant html refering to my SPA starting point. I have a "#map" element (with the 4 controls referred to in the css/stylus, a "#editControl > button, a ".button" element. The vue single file component just has the html #map element and the ".button" element. Other elements are 'js generated'.

Comment: That's fine that they are JS generated.. create a http://jsfiddle.net with the relevant code and we can have a look there. The problem at the moment is you're trying to shorted the lookup of code we cannot see.. We cant make suggestions if we dont know what we're looking at

Answer (score 0):

Not the smartest question probably. Anyway, I solved it by first using:

```
.mapboxgl-control-container .mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left .button,
#editControl > button
```

as selector which was not picked up and then -to see why it was overruled- looking into 'Chrome developer tools > elements > style' which css was 'on top' for one of the control elements which led me to this selector which works fine in my case:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-group > button,
#editControl > button
  min-height 0
  border-radius 0
```

Answer (score -3):

css 3 have mixins, just like less or sass. For example

```css
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    @apply --button-style;
}

:root {
    --button-style: {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 30px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: blue;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 54px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
  .btnOne {
    background: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Mixins</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <button class="btnOne"> One </button>
        <button class="btnTwo"> Two </button>
        <button class="btnThree"> Three </button>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

In this [example](https://github.com/Neha/css3-demos/tree/master/cssMixins) @apply function is mixin. But warning! Not work in IE 9

Comment: I sympathize you. But why require IE 9. I know script, witch talk user change browser to newest versions. [link to this constructor](https://tech.yandex.com/browser/constructor/)

Comment: This works **only** in Chome, and is behind a flag, so for general usage it is a no no

Comment: @LGSon: I'm not surprised an implementation even exists in Chrome, given that the author of the spec in the first place is on the Chrome team, even though the spec itself is unofficial. But this is the entire reason why I'm against the idea of running implementations of unofficial specs - because then people take them to be official, like you see here.

Comment: @BoltClock Can't agree more